# How to Set multiple Between Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which contains students details.
For Example:

```
Name   Grade Number of subtractions
Josef  100   0
Daniel 90    2
Diana  50    100
Koby   30    200
```

I want to get the names of students that their Grade is between 0 and 50 and their Number Of Subtractions is between 100 and 200, for the example it will retrun Diana and Koby only

Comment: and your current code?

Comment: SELECT Name from ExampleTBL where Grade Between 0 and 50 and NumOf  Between 100 and 200

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Can you filter for just the grade? And just the subscriptions?

Comment: i need to get the name that its collumn value are between the specified grades range and the specified subscriptions name, i need them both

Comment: worked now, tbh i needed to do it for more than 2 betweens, but it was the same way, thank you @S.Akbari

Comment: @OBZ You're Welcome. It would be great if you also vote for an answer when you accept it. You can click up arrow near the answer to upvote. It's recommended and reasonable. More information https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [between](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) and [`And`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) or [`Or`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) operators:

```
select name
from studentsdetails 
where (Grade between 0 and 50)
and (NumberOfSubtractions between 100 and 200)
```

Or with `Or`:

```
select name
from studentsdetails 
where (Grade between 0 and 50)
Or (NumberOfSubtractions between 100 and 200)
```

Comment: that is the same query im using now, it works if i put only the grade but when im adding the numberofsubtractions it doesnt :/

Comment: @OBZ I didn't understand your mean correctly. You might need `Or` instead of `And`?

Comment: i really think my example shows my mean tbh, i want to get the name that has the both range conditon applied, with using or it doesnt mean that it has one?

Comment: @OBZ the `OR` return the names,  if either or both operands is true and returns false otherwise. But in `And`, it returns names, if both operands are true and returns false otherwise. SO you should decide which of them are more appropriate in your case.

Comment: so i need that the both operands will be true tho